# How can I assign a custom job ID to the job added to a queue in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5, jobs

I would like to delete a job from the queue. To easily identify the job, I would like to assign it a custom job ID. How can I do this on Laravel 5.2?

Comment: What queue driver do you use?

Comment: @ArminSam I am planning to use Redis.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to use Redis, you can create a dictionary of `customJobId => actualJobId` in memory for each job that you push to the queue.

So, if you want to delete a specific job with a customJobID of `xyz`, then first you have to find the actualJobId from the dictionary and then find and remove the key belonging to that job id from redis.

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in my mind and I did something similar. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I this this will help , you can give the job unique name by

$job = (new YourJobClass())->onQueue('customIdYouNeed');
dispatch($job);

Comment: What you have suggested is to add the job to a specific queue.